# Relating Table Without Distorting Data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I've spent all day trying to get this query to work and would love to see if anybody can point out where I'm going wrong.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT   CONCAT(STUDENT.FirstName, ' ', 
         STUDENT.LastName) AS 'Student Name', 
         `UNIT`.UnitCode, SUM(STUDENT_ASSESSMENT.MarkAwarded) AS 'Sum of Marks Awarded'
FROM     `STUDENT_ASSESSMENT`
JOIN     `STUDENT` 
ON       `STUDENT_ASSESSMENT`.StudentID = `STUDENT`.StudentID
JOIN     `ASSESSMENT` 
ON       `STUDENT_ASSESSMENT`.AssessmentID = `ASSESSMENT`.AssessmentID
JOIN     `UNIT` 
ON       `ASSESSMENT`.Unitcode = `UNIT`.UnitCode
GROUP BY STUDENT.StudentID
ORDER BY `STUDENT`.LastName, `STUDENT`.FirstName, `UNIT`.UnitCode
```

It works fine and does what i want it to.

Working Query Result:

[image]

However I'm trying to JOIN a table called UNIT_ENROLMENT which has attributes i need to access. When I try joining it ruins my data.

```
SELECT   CONCAT(STUDENT.FirstName, ' ', 
         STUDENT.LastName) AS 'Student Name', 
         `UNIT`.UnitCode, 
         SUM(STUDENT_ASSESSMENT.MarkAwarded) AS 'Sum of Marks Awarded', 
         `UNIT_ENROLMENT`.FinalGrade
FROM     `STUDENT_ASSESSMENT`
JOIN     `UNIT_ENROLMENT` 
ON       `STUDENT_ASSESSMENT`.StudentID = `UNIT_ENROLMENT`.StudentID
JOIN     `STUDENT` 
ON       `UNIT_ENROLMENT`.StudentID = `STUDENT`.StudentID
JOIN     `ASSESSMENT` 
ON       `STUDENT_ASSESSMENT`.AssessmentID = `ASSESSMENT`.AssessmentID
JOIN     `UNIT` 
ON       `ASSESSMENT`.Unitcode = `UNIT`.UnitCode
WHERE    `UNIT_ENROLMENT`.Year = '2017'
GROUP BY STUDENT.StudentID
ORDER BY `STUDENT`.LastName, `STUDENT`.FirstName, `UNIT_ENROLMENT`.Session, `UNIT`.UnitCode
```

Distorted result:

[image]

If any other information is required please comment. Any help is very much appricated

Comment: Please describe the relations.

Comment: Could a student have multiple UNIT_ENROLMENT rows associated with it? Is there any other column other than StudentID that must identify a unique  row? Like maybe UNIT CODE?

Comment: A student can enroll in multiple units correct, so there are multiple units (different rows) for each student in UNIT_ENROLMENT. Yes UnitCode is also a primary key in UNIT_ENROLMENT

Comment: you need to match it with unitcode also then...that's why one of your students gets double her marks...coz she gets included twice...just  a guess.

Comment: Tried to implement the recommendation but get an error #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'UNIT_ENROLMENT', for the following query

Comment: SELECT CONCAT(STUDENT.FirstName, ' ', STUDENT.LastName) AS 'Student Name', `UNIT`.UnitCode, SUM(STUDENT_ASSESSMENT.MarkAwarded) AS 'Sum of Marks Awarded', `UNIT_ENROLMENT`.FinalGrade

FROM `STUDENT_ASSESSMENT`
JOIN `UNIT_ENROLMENT` ON `STUDENT_ASSESSMENT`.StudentID = `UNIT_ENROLMENT`.StudentID
JOIN `ASSESSMENT` ON `STUDENT_ASSESSMENT`.AssessmentID = `ASSESSMENT`.AssessmentID
JOIN `UNIT_ENROLMENT` ON `ASSESSMENT`.UnitCode = `UNIT_ENROLMENT`.UnitCode
JOIN `STUDENT` ON `UNIT_ENROLMENT`.StudentID = `STUDENT`.StudentID
JOIN `UNIT` ON `UNIT_ENROLMENT`.UnitCode = `UNIT`.UnitCode

Comment: WHERE `UNIT_ENROLMENT`.Year = '2017'

GROUP BY STUDENT.StudentID

ORDER BY `STUDENT`.LastName, `STUDENT`.FirstName, `UNIT_ENROLMENT`.Session, `UNIT`.UnitCode

Comment: Could you post an sql fiddle?

Comment: The content is to large :(

Comment: Backticks and  error #1066 mean you are using MySQL not SQL Server. I have removed the erroneous tag.

Comment: try my answer ...

Comment: Tried everything, still no luck. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've shared, you could try this:

Join UNIT_ENROLMENT after your join with ASSESSMENT and UNIT:

```
SELECT   CONCAT(STUDENT.FirstName, ' ', 
     STUDENT.LastName) AS 'Student Name', 
     `UNIT`.UnitCode, 
     SUM(STUDENT_ASSESSMENT.MarkAwarded) AS 'Sum of Marks Awarded', 
     `UNIT_ENROLMENT`.FinalGrade
FROM     `STUDENT_ASSESSMENT`
JOIN     `STUDENT` 
ON       `STUDENT_ASSESSMENT`.StudentID = `STUDENT`.StudentID
JOIN     `ASSESSMENT` 
ON       `STUDENT_ASSESSMENT`.AssessmentID = `ASSESSMENT`.AssessmentID
JOIN     `UNIT` 
ON       `ASSESSMENT`.Unitcode = `UNIT`.UnitCode
JOIN     `UNIT_ENROLMENT` 
ON       `STUDENT_ASSESSMENT`.StudentID = `UNIT_ENROLMENT`.StudentID
AND  `UNIT_ENROLMENT`.UnitCode = `ASSESSMENT`.Unitcode
WHERE    `UNIT_ENROLMENT`.Year = '2017'
GROUP BY STUDENT.StudentID
ORDER BY `STUDENT`.LastName, `STUDENT`.FirstName, `UNIT_ENROLMENT`.Session, `UNIT`.UnitCode
```

Comment: Tried everything, still no luck. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'UNIT_ENROLMENT.StudentID' in 'on clause'

Comment: Great...if it helped you, pls accept it as the answer.